# How Do I Code a Contact List Program in C++ Using Functions & Vectors?

Tags: c++, function, vector

I am trying to write a contact list program in the C++ programming language and I think I have a good base set up for one. The premise of the program is that two vectors of values are entered. One vector for the contact name and another for the phone number. Once a few of these values are taken in by the program, a single contact name is supposed to signify to the program that its corresponding phone number should be outputted.

(Note: The '3' is supposed to tell the program how many values are to be stored in each vector. In this case, it is 3 contact names and 3 phone numbers.)

**Ex. Input: 3 Joe 123-5432 Linda 983-4123 Frank 867-5309 Frank**

**Ex. Output: 867-5309**

But I am getting an error message that reads, "**Exited with return code -11 (SIGSEGV).**" I'm not sure where I could be leaking any memory but maybe I just can't see it.

Any help that can fix this error would be greatly appreciated.

Below is code that I have written so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string GetPhoneNumber(vector<string> nameVec, vector<string> phoneNumberVec, string contactName)  {
   
   string theName;
   string thePhoneNum;
   string theContName;
   int N;
   int nElements;
   
   cin >> N;
   
   cin >> theName;
   cin >> thePhoneNum;
   cin >> theName;
   cin >> thePhoneNum;
   cin >> theName;
   cin >> thePhoneNum;
   
   nameVec.push_back(theName);
   phoneNumberVec.push_back(thePhoneNum);
   
   cin >> contactName;
   
   nElements = phoneNumberVec.size(); 
   
   for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++)  {
      if (i == N)  {
         return phoneNumberVec.at(i);
      }
   }
   
}

int main() {
   
   vector<string> nameVec;
   vector<string> phoneNumberVec;
   string contactName;
   
   cout << GetPhoneNumber(nameVec, phoneNumberVec, contactName) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the error? In that case, extract and provide a [mcve]. If you want improvements on a working program, use codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Using the sample inputs that I provided and the code that I have provided, no more and no less, you should be able to reproduce the exact same error that I am experiencing.

Comment: @CritAnnihilation Did your compiler warn you that you are failing to return a `std::string` from the function?

Comment: The `GetPhoneNumber` function is declared to return `std::string`, but sometimes it doesn't return anything. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: The compiler for the learning program that I am using, Zybooks, didn't warn me that I am failing to return a ```std::string```.

Comment: @CritAnnihilation [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afbe4ab53a3ec808).  You need to know what tools are being used under the hood.  You should know the compiler, version of the compiler, and compiler flags used to build whatever application you're building.

Comment: I see that the error is on the line that says ```string theName;``` but I am not quite sure how to approach fixing this. Coding in C++ is fairly new for me.

Comment: @CritAnnihilation -- What do you return if `i` is never equal to `N`?

Comment: @PaulMckenzie -- If ```i``` is never equal to ```N``` then the program outputs the correct phone number for its corresponding contact name. But, why is that? Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are supposed to return a `std::string` from `GetPhoneNumber`, but there are code paths where no return is specified.

What happens is that the program has now invoked *undefined behavior*, as returning no value from a function that's supposed to return a value leads to undefined behavior occurring.

The fix is to return a `std::string` from the `GetPhoneNumber` function from all code paths.  Namely right here:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++)  {
      if (i == N)  {
         return phoneNumberVec.at(i);
      }
   }
   return ""; // or some appropriate string.
 }
```

To prove that this is the issue, if you do not have that `return` statement, and instead did this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++)  {
      if (i == N)  {
         return phoneNumberVec.at(i);
      }
   }
   std::cout << "There will be a problem" << std::endl;
 }
```

You will see the string,

`There will be a problem`

outputted, proving you are reaching that point in the function without returning a value.

Here is a [live example](https://ideone.com/WEN7Zl).

---

The other issue is that `i` could never equal `N`, since a `std::vector` uses 0-based indexing.  If `N` is 1, then the highest index for `i` will be `0`.

The fix is to compare `i` to `N-1`.

Comment: This fixes the error code but if ```i = N``` still, the program will not output the correct phone number.

Comment: See the edit. You would see that `i` could never equal `N` in that loop, thus falling out of the loop and not returning anything.  But you see that the error caused two bugs to be exposed.  The segmentation fault that you were seeing was caused by the non-return of a `std::string`, so the answer mainly addresses that error.

Comment: Even if I change the code to ```(i == N-1)``` and I include ```return "";``` I still don't know how to get the result of the ```return phoneNumberVec.at(i);``` line into my ```int(main)``` method.

Comment: The answer given is pertinent to the original question that was asked in the thread.  Anything else is off-topic.  I suggest you debug your code and see exactly what those values are, as that is a different issue.